# Ethernet interface changes name

Tags: ethernet, interface, netplan

My ethernet interface changed name from enp6s0 to enp4s0 after a power loss. Something like this has happened before, but don't recall exact details. I modified  /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml to get my ethernet running. How do I prevent this from happening again ? I'm on Ubuntu server 18.04

Edit:
50-cloud-init.yaml file

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp4s0:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
```

Board and bios :

```
dmidecode -t baseboard
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: BIOSTAR Group
        Product Name: TB250-BTC PRO
        Version:
        Serial Number: None
        Asset Tag: None
        Features:
                Board is a hosting board
                Board is replaceable
        Location In Chassis: None
        Chassis Handle: 0x0003
        Type: Motherboard
        Contained Object Handles: 0


dmidecode -s bios-version
5.12
```

Comment: Get rid of netplan and use /etc/network/interfaces. Old ways are better.

Comment: Is this a server? How many etherports do you have? Single card with multiple ports?

Comment: @Gravemind not very helpful. Servers use netplan.

Comment: Very much not helpful.  Netplan doesn't cause device names to change unless you tell it to, and /etc/network/interfaces absolutely doesn't have a way of handling devices changing names.

Comment: @slangasek my point is - netplan is not the best way for configuring your DebianLike OS network interfaces.

Comment: @heynnema I got single card with single port.

Comment: The only thing I can think of... for an motherboard ethernet port (not a PCI card) is that something changed with the BIOS. Have you checked for any recent BIOS updates? What make/model computer or motherboard? Edit your question and show me your .yaml file.

Comment: Use `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to see your current BIOS version.

Comment: @heynnema Edited question with info you asked.

Comment: It looks like your BIOS might be old. Their web site doesn't articulate version numbers, but 5.12 looks like the original? See https://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=884#download

Comment: ok, thanks. Will update and hopefully this never happens again.

Answer (score 1):

These network interface names are specifically designed to be persistent and predictable, and not change even if you reinstall your operating system.  If this is a physical machine and the device name changed without you moving network hardware within the machine, this sounds like a serious issue that warrants a bug report against the kernel

If this is a virtual machine, then something may have changed in the configuration of your hypervisor, which may be out of your control.

Normally there is no reason to specially handle the possibility of a device name changing because it's not supposed to happen.  But netplan does allow you to apply configuration based on matches other than the device name using a device `match` section.  This lets you match on properties such as mac address, or even apply your settings to any device matching a device name glob (such as `eth*`  or `en*`) which can be useful if you know you will only have one network device but can't be sure its name won't change.

Comment: This is a physical machine and I haven't moved any network hardware, since I'm using integrated ethernet card. I'm occasionally moving some other hardware tho, peripherals and graphic cards.

Comment: You say : These network interface names are specifically designed to be persistent and predictable. What does that exactly mean ? Like in my case my interface is named enp4s0, what these numbers exactly represent ?

Comment: @John enp4s0 means ethernet, port 4, slot 0